# Should we remove the "documents" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

After a short [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24920756#24920756) in the DMZ with @AviD, I started removing the [office](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office) tag from posts.
In the process, I came along the [documents](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/documents) tag. This tag seems too broad and ambiguous to be useful. It is used to refer tag questions about security documents, confidentiality of documents, and modifying documents.

So, I suggest we burninate this tag.

Comment: All of those cases sound much better with standalone tags. Maybe we should create the standalone tags and swap them in editing, then burn the tag?

Answer (score 3):

So I've been browsing the documents tab, and I have to agree. We should burn the tag... Or replace it with more meaningful tags. That'd be my vote. Instead of just having documents maybe we should break it out into security documents(possibly not policy, but releases, updates, blogs), security of documents, and securely modifying documents.

Of course as you can plainly see I'm not the best tag maker ever(hence why I DON'T make tags), but just burning it seems like a bad idea, when really what it needs is a refactoring.